# Java Graphics Will Not Display

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

Here is my code:

```
package survival;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Survival extends JFrame { 
    private static int applicationWidth = 1400;
    private static int applicationHeight = 900;  

    public Survival() {
        setTitle("Survival");
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(applicationWidth, applicationHeight);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Test", 0, 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Survival();
    }
}
```

Why isn't "Test" showing up?

Comment: I usually cast the `Graphics` object to `Graphics2D`. Not sure if that's the issue or not.

Comment: 1) It is generally folly to be overriding `paint()` in a Swing top-level container.  Instead override `paintComponent()` in a `JComponent` or `JPanel`, then add that to the TLC.  2) Then set the `preferredSize()` of the custom component, add it to the frame and call `pack()`.  That will ensure the rendering area is 1400x900. 3) Swing GUIs should be created & updated on the EDT.  4) At co-ordinates of 0x0, the `String` will be largely invisible.  5) Just a side note, but if you can get a GUI to fail at 400x300, no need to set it to 1400x900!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke paint() method of super class. (Article - [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/))

```
 public Survival() {
        setTitle("Survival");
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(applicationWidth, applicationHeight);
        setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);    
        g.drawString("Test", 120, 120); //change the co-odrinates
    }
```

Override the paintComponent of JPanel.

```
 public Survival() {
        setTitle("Survival");
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(applicationWidth, applicationHeight);
        setVisible(true);
        add(new DrawPanel());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     }

   class DrawPanel extends JPanel
   {
    @Override
    protected  void paintComponent( Graphics g){
       g.drawString("Test", 220,220);
      }
   }
```

Comment: @ConnerRuhl - Drawing on JFrame is very tricky. You have to use JPanel and override the paintComponet method.

Answer (score 3):

Do not override `paint`. Whenever you customize a component, override `paintComponent`.

**Example -**

```
@Override
protected final void paintComponent(final Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    final Graphics gCopy = g.create(); // Prevents clobbering
    gCopy.drawString("Test", 0, 0);
    gCopy.dispose();
}
```

Comment: @AVD, Why? Do you want to make a comment about it?

Comment: I have two observations: You should invoke `super.paintComponent()`, as suggested [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html), and I don't see a reason to clone the graphics context.

Comment: @trashgod, In this case, there really isn't a reason to clone the graphics object, but I was trying to reinforce good practice. As for invoking `super.paintComponent`, you're absolutely right. It's been a long day.

Comment: well ... "good practice" depends on context and its competing constraints ;-) The force to clone the graphics is to return it in the same state you got it. The more general force (for code sanity) is to not clutter any code by unnessary lines. So if the first doesn't exist (trivially, as there is no change whatever) the second can flourish fully. In other words: you would have a hard task to pass that snippet through my review :-)